# Ignite - How does it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I got a report using ignite tool which stated that one of my stored procedure (on sql server 2008) is taking 40.2% of total sql execution time.

Comment: More details please.  What exactly are you curious about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if the proc is called tens of thousand of times a day or if the proc is running for 16 hours with 30 nested cursors...take a look at how many times it was executed...you can also drill down per hour in ignite and take a look at IO